When using FindFit to fit a large dataset with multiple sine functions, a step size error occur
My dataset looks like
datatandA = Import["dataForQuestionFindFit20240528.csv"];
ListPlot[datatandA]


and the corresponding FFT spectrum looks like
SamplingInterval = datatandA[[2, 1]] - datatandA[[1, 1]];
funcFFT[datatandA, SamplingInterval][[2]]


There are multiple peaks. So I fit this data using multiple sine functions:
SamplingInterval = datatandA[[2, 1]] - datatandA[[1, 1]]
{fitShowA, datafitResultA} = 
  func\[Delta]A[datatandA, SamplingInterval];

The result looks good:

However, I encountered the following error:

What exactly does this error mean, and how can I resolve it?
Thank you!
The dataset can be download here. And the funtions are attached below.

ssf[n_, dt_] := 
  If[EvenQ[n], RotateRight[Range[-n/2, n/2 - 1]/(n dt), n/2], 
   RotateRight[Range[-(n - 1)/2, (n - 1)/2]/(n dt), (n + 1)/2]];
funcFFT[dataRePT_, SamplingInterval_] :=
 Module[{peaksdataFFT, dataPeriodogram},
  timelength = Length@dataRePT;
  dataFFT = 
   Fourier[dataRePT[[All, 2]]][[1 ;; Ceiling[timelength/2]]];
  
  Fv = ssf[timelength, SamplingInterval][[1 ;; Ceiling[timelength/2]]];
  dataPeriodogram = Transpose@{Fv, Abs@dataFFT}; 
  peaksdataFFT = 
   FindPeaks[dataPeriodogram[[All, 2]], 0, 0, .0000001];
  peaks = (Transpose@{Fv, dataFFT})[[
    IntegerPart[First /@ peaksdataFFT]]]; 
  plot = ListPlot[{dataPeriodogram, Abs@peaks}, 
    PlotRange -> {{8, 10}, All}, Joined -> {True, False}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive@{PointSize[0.01]}]; {peaks, plot}]


funcFit[peaks_, dataRePT_] := 
 Module[{fitResult, fitParameters}, 
  fitParameters = {{a1, 
     If[peaks[[1, 1]] == 0, 1/Sqrt[timelength] Re[peaks[[1, 2]]], 
      1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[1, 2]]]]}, {a2, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[2, 2]]]}, {a3, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[3, 2]]]}, {a4, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[4, 2]]]}, {a5, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[5, 2]]]}, {a6, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[6, 2]]]}, {a7, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[7, 2]]]}, {a8, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[8, 2]]]}, {a9, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[9, 2]]]}, {a10, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[10, 2]]]}, {a11, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[11, 2]]]}, {a12, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Re[peaks[[12, 2]]]}, {f1, 
     peaks[[1, 1]]}, {f2, peaks[[2, 1]]}, {f3, peaks[[3, 1]]}, {f4, 
     peaks[[4, 1]]}, {f5, peaks[[5, 1]]}, {f6, peaks[[6, 1]]}, {f7, 
     peaks[[7, 1]]}, {f8, peaks[[8, 1]]}, {f9, peaks[[9, 1]]}, {f10, 
     peaks[[10, 1]]}, {f11, peaks[[11, 1]]}, {f12, 
     peaks[[12, 1]]}, {b1, 
     If[peaks[[1, 1]] == 0, 1/Sqrt[timelength] Im[peaks[[1, 2]]], 
      1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[1, 2]]]]}, {b2, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[2, 2]]]}, {b3, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[3, 2]]]}, {b4, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[4, 2]]]}, {b5, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[5, 2]]]}, {b6, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[6, 2]]]}, {b7, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[7, 2]]]}, {b8, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[8, 2]]]}, {b9, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[9, 2]]]}, {b10, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[10, 2]]]}, {b11, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[11, 2]]]}, {b12, 
     1/Sqrt[timelength] 2 Im[peaks[[12, 2]]]}};
  fitExpression = 
   a1 Cos[2 Pi f1 t] + a2 Cos[2 Pi f2 t] + a3 Cos[2 Pi f3 t] + 
    a4 Cos[2 Pi f4 t] + a5 Cos[2 Pi f5 t] + a6 Cos[2 Pi f6 t] + 
    a7 Cos[2 Pi f7 t] + a8 Cos[2 Pi f8 t] + a9 Cos[2 Pi f9 t] + 
    a10 Cos[2 Pi f10 t] + a11 Cos[2 Pi f11 t] + a12 Cos[2 Pi f12 t] + 
    b1 Sin[2 Pi f1 t] + b2 Sin[2 Pi f2 t] + b3 Sin[2 Pi f3 t] + 
    b4 Sin[2 Pi f4 t] + b5 Sin[2 Pi f5 t] + b6 Sin[2 Pi f6 t] + 
    b7 Sin[2 Pi f7 t] + b8 Sin[2 Pi f8 t] + b9 Sin[2 Pi f9 t] + 
    b10 Sin[2 Pi f10 t] + b11 Sin[2 Pi f11 t] + b12 Sin[2 Pi f12 t];
  fitResult = 
   FindFit[dataRePT, fitExpression, fitParameters, t(*,
    Method->{"NMinimize"},MaxIterations->1000*)(*,MaxIterations->
    2 5000*)(*,Method->"Newton"*)(*,WorkingPrecision->25*)]; 
  fitResult]

func\[Delta]A[datatandA_, SamplingInterval_] := 
 Module[{fitShow, dataRePT, preal, datafitResult},
  dataRePT = datatandA;
  preal = ListPlot[dataRePT, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True];
  {peaks, plotFFT} = funcFFT[dataRePT, SamplingInterval];
  peaksSorted = Sort[peaks, Abs@#1[[2]] > Abs@#2[[2]] &];
  fitResult = funcFit[peaksSorted, dataRePT];
  finalTime = dataRePT[[-1, 1]];
  datafitResult = 
   ParallelTable[{t, Evaluate[fitExpression /. fitResult(*[t]*)]}, {t,
      0, finalTime, SamplingInterval}];
  fitShow = 
   Show[preal, 
    ListPlot[datafitResult, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], 
     Joined -> True]]; {fitShow, datafitResult}]



Please provide a plain text file with your data.

@JimB Do you mean converting the “.mat” file to a “.txt” file?

Yes.  Otherwise warnings appear saying that your current file is executable and "Do you really want to continue?"  That reduces the number of folks willing to help.

@JimB Thanks for the reminder. The update has been done.

This just an extended comment.  While understand that just about any function can be approximated with a sum of sines and cosines, I wonder if your data is generated by a simpler process.
A plot of the 200,001 data points looks like the following:
ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1/12, ImageSize -> Full, Frame -> True]


A plot of just about any subset of points looks like the following:
ListPlot[data[[500 ;; 1500]], AspectRatio -> 1/12, ImageSize -> Full, 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.002]]


So it looks like there are just two sine waves:  one for the size of the amplitude of the second sine wave.  If so, that would seem simpler than the 12 sines and 12 cosines (resulting in 48 parameters).

Hi, JimB. There are at least six primary peaks in the FFT spectrum (see the second figure in my question). The more components of the Fourier series used, the more precise the result should be. Is that correct? I want the results to be as accurate as possible, which is why I chose to include so many sine and cosine terms.

What I'm trying to guess at (as I don't know the subject matter) is by looking at the data if there might be some simpler underlying structure where one models the amplitude and frequency as separate functions of the horizontal/time variable.  One can throw a zillion sines and cosines at the data and get a good fit but that just describes the data as opposed to "explaining" the data.

While the residuals from your model are small, a plot of the residuals from your current model still shows considerable structure remaining:  residuals =  Transpose[{datafitResultA[[200001 ;; 400001, 1]],  datatandA[[All, 2]] - datafitResultA[[200001 ;; 400001, 2]]}]; ListPlot[residuals, AspectRatio -> 1/12, ImageSize -> Full].  That's not to be meant as a complaint.  It's just that if you're looking for the predictions to be as accurate as possible, there's still more to explain or there might be an alternative model structure.
